# How to save the contents of MATLAB's Command Window to a file?

Tags: matlab, file, save, command-window

I want to save everything in the "Command Window" to a file automatically. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: By "command window", you mean the textual contents of the window, or the contents of the local workspace?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a few options available for saving content from the Command Window:

- You can do this using the [DIARY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diary.html) command. You could even automate this so that it always records what you do by modifying your [`startup.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html) file to turn on text logging:

  ```
  diary('myTextLog.txt');  %# Text will be appended if this file already exists
  ```

  And then modify your [`finish.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/finish.html) file to turn logging off:

  ```
  diary('off');
  ```

  This will automatically store the entire text content of the Command Window for every MATLAB session, which could grow into a rather large text file.
- Another option besides using the DIARY command and modifying your `startup.m` and `finish.m` files is to start MATLAB using the [`-logfile` option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html):

  ```
  matlab -logfile "myTextLog.txt"
  ```

  Although I'm not sure if this will overwrite the text file or append to it each time you start MATLAB.
- If you're just wanting to save the output from evaluating one or more expressions, you can use the [EVALC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) function to evaluate a string containing your expression and capture the output that would normally go to the command window in a character array. You can then print this character array to a file using [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).
- Finally, if you're not interested in saving the *displayed* output from commands you type, but you instead just want to store the *commands* themselves, then the [Command History](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-history.html) is what you want. MATLAB automatically stores a `history.m` file with a maximum size of 200,000 bytes, deleting the oldest entries when newer ones are added.

Comment: Note that this needs to be called at the start the session; it will only save all output occurring after the diary command was called.

Comment: Just add diary to startup.m. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html  Then just generate a new diary file name based off the launch time or something.

Comment: In Octave, type `history_file` to see the path where the history is being saved.

Comment: The equivalent of the above for MATLAB is [`prefdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prefdir.html).

Comment: If you go for the diary solution and you want to name the diary file based on any variable, use `diary(filename)`, e.g. `diary([datestr(now,'yyyymmdd_HHMM'),'.txt])`. Otherwise, `diary filename` will simply take `filename` as name (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22149660).