# Matlab Diary out put information and error messages

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB I am using the diary function create a text file and log my output and any error messages that might occur. I have two issues using the diary function.

1) When an error message occurs it comes out in a html format, please see an example below. Is there anyway for the error message just to be output as plain text?

2) Also everytime I run the code I would like a new dairy file and for the information not to be appended.

```
 Error in <a href="matlab:helpUtils.errorDocCallback('upload_rawrets', 'C:\Matlab\output\upload_rawrets.m', 99)" style="font-weight:bold">upload_rawrets</a> (<a href="matlab: opentoline('C:\Matlab\output\upload_rawrets.m',99,0)">line 99</a>)
export_full         = [export_full; repmat(companies, int_obs, 1) reshape(pricedatew, int_cos * int_obs, 1)
num2cell(reshape(ret_usd, int_cos * int_obs, 1))];
```

Answer (score 3):

1) No, there's no way to change that - it's a documented behaviour of the `diary` function.

2) At the start of your code, you can use the command `diary(filename)`, which sets `diary` to output to the file `filename`. Construct a filename based on something such as the time you run the code, such as:

```
filename = ['mydiary', datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-SS'), '.txt'];`
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I found for 2) that I can just use the delete method in Matlab. So delete 'myFileName.txt' before creating me diary. The output though of error messages is very unfriendly though!