# MATLAB Command History: how to save back up of existing history

Tags: matlab

According to this link:

[How to save contents of MATLAB's command windows to in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833356/how-to-save-contents-of-matlabs-command-windows-to-in-a-file)

I can back up my commends going forward using `diary` which is great:

However I would also like to back up my existing command history, I assume the command history is stored in a text file somewhere correct?
If so can I just copy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the ["Save Entire Command History" submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9291-save-entire-command-history), which will let you save all your command history, not just the last 20k allowed by MATLAB.

Comment: Wow that might be even better! Does anyone have first hand experience of using the submission shown in the answer above?

Comment: @Bazman I've used something like this in the past, maybe this one but i can't recall.  It did as it said, but it took a little setup.

Answer (score 7):

Type `prefdir` on Matlab and it will give you a folder.

Your command history is in that folder, in a file called `history.m`.

Comment: `prefdir` was the hint I was looking for. But the file called `History.xml` in Matlab R2014b and R2015b. A simple copy from 2014 to 2015 works fine.