# MATLAB: how to get the specs of the host machine

Tags: matlab, specifications

I have a MATLAB program that I intend to run on different machines. Is there a way to get, from within MATLAB itself, the following info:

- Name of machine
- Specs of machine, especially processor and memory configuration
- Number of cores deployed for MATLAB

I know the command `computer` but I require more than what it outputs. I'd like to write all the info above to a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the following:

**1)** To check the type of computer on which MATLAB is executing, use: `computer` .

**2)**  The following displays information about your Windows:

```
winqueryreg('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',...
     'Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion','ProductName')
```

or in general, to get information about the OS, use: `feature('GetOS')`.

**3)** To check number of processors, use:  `getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS')`.

**4)** To check CPU information, use: `feature('GetCPU')`.

**5)** To get information about cores, use: `feature('numCores')` .

**6)** To check memory used by MATLAB, total physical memory and some other information, use: `memory`.

**Note that:**
 Some of the above are undocumented and taken from [**Yair Altman's blog**](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function).

Finally, to write data in a text file, you can use:  [**`fprintf`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) .

Comment: I need to learn what these are but it seems to be exactly what I want. Thank you so much for this and the link.

Comment: Would you know how to get all the output of feature('numCores')? If I assign a variable to it, I only get a number whereas when I run the command as is, it prints out 4 lines with more detailed info. I'd like to get those 4 lines.

Comment: When you assign it to a variable, it gives you *Number of cores deployed for MATLAB*, which you originally asked in the question. The rest of the information is a bonus! And if you want to store all that information in a text file, here is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833356/how-to-save-contents-of-matlabs-command-windows-to-in-a-file

Comment: Got i! I found another work around using evalc. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @yurnero Would you mind sharing how you used `evalc` here?

Comment: Of course. I use `memoryinfo   = evalc('feature memstats');` which dumps the entire output of `feature('memstats')` into the string `memoryinfo`. Then I manually extract the relevant info from `memoryinfo`. Cheers.

Comment: @yurnero For information about cores, you probably meant to write: `evalc('feature numCores');` but anyway I understand that. I also learnt something new 